# Why can't I output .Rmd as .pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I'm using R and RStudio with Windows 10. And when I try to output an .Rmd file as .pdf, the horrible error below occurs:

[image: errors]

I did read the debugging intruction (https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging) , but adding the line

```
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

didn't really help. Also, no missing LaTex packages could be detected in the error log as suggested.

```
> tinytex::parse_packages("Homework4_1.log")
I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log Homework4_1.log.
```

I have no ideas what else I can do now. Can anybody help me out here? Thanks a million!

---

Thank you, guys! I reinstalled TinyTex as Ralf suggested and everything went back normal. I'm including the log file [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/91a349b730b205df153e5a5f42035fad20191015161804/fa802b) in case somebody else would find it insightful, though.

Comment: Can you show the complete `Homework4_1.log` file?

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images. Use (formatted) text instead. Anyway, your TinyTeX installation seems to be broken. I would try to reinstall it using `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I reinstalled TinyTex as Ralf suggested and things came back on track again. I'll post what's in the error log in case it provides insight into anything for anyone else, though. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh sorry, the log file has too many characters. I can't just copy and paste it here.